# Creating pdf with Spring, IText, watermark

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext

I have an application that creates a PDF file using Java, Spring and IText.

I want to add a watermark to the pdf.

I have found plenty of examples of adding a watermark to an already saved PDF.  I want to add the watermark before the PDF is saved.

I found an example of doing what I want using ITextSharp, however, it is for .NET.  I am using the following code in my class that creates the pdf document.

```
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map model, Document document, PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    ProgramCmd programCmd = (ProgramCmd) request.getSession().getAttribute("programCmd ");
    List<Courses> list = programCmd.getCoursesList();
    List<Events> eventsList = programCmd.getEventsList();
    FONT_SIZE_16_BOLD.setColor(232, 177, 0);
    // Print Header
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Title",FONT_SIZE_16_BOLD);
    paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(paragraph);
    paragraph = new Paragraph("***This is Not Official***",FONT_SIZE_12_BOLD);
    paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(paragraph);
    paragraph = new Paragraph("Create Date: " + todaysDate,FONT_SIZE_12_BOLD);
    paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(paragraph);
}
```

Please let me know if you want me to post other code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first edition of the book ["iText in Action"](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/) has an example "WatermarkExample.java" in chapter 14. You can download the source of the example at [Manning's website](http://www.manning.com/lowagie/), though of course, I also encourage you to purchase the book!

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have this working partially using the example you pointed me to, but I have an issue I hope you can help me with. I am using PdfPTables in my pdf.  The watermark, whether I use images or text, does not seem to appear over the tables. Is this an inherent problem with iText?  Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you're adding the watermark under the existing content. If the existing content is opaque, it will cover the watermark. If you want the watermark to cover the existing content, you need to use getDirectContent() instead of getDirectContentUnder(). You may also want to make your watermark transparent: http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=241

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for promoting my book, GreyBeardedGeek (deserves an upvote).

Let me elaborate on the matter:

It's not clear if you want to add the watermark *while* you're creating the document (that's done with page events), or *after* the document is created (that's done with `PdfStamper`).

These are examples of both options:

1. In http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=105 we extend `PdfPageEventHelper` and implement the `onEndPage()` method. As documented, you shouldn't add anything to the Document class, nor use the onStartPage() method to add content. (More info in [iText in Action - Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/)).
2. In http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=119 we add a background to an existing PDF using `PdfStamper` and `PdfReader`. You don't need to have a file on disk to create a `PdfReader` instance. You can create the file in memory first (e.g. using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`) and pass the bytes to the `PdfReader` constructor.

Comment: thanks for your response.  I am using the PdfPageEventHelper b/c I want to watermark while I am creating the document.  I now have this working, except for the problem I noted in my response to @GrayBeardedGeek.  Any help you can give me will be appreciated.  Thanks.